# How to start project with spring boot redux and react

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, redux, react-redux

I would like to start creating an application that will use Java on the backend and frontend react and redux. I tried to find a tutorial where it would be described how to start a project that will use these technologies (spring boot, redux 4 and react). Unfortunately, I did not find any such tutorial. Could you please help me and give me some tips how to get started? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

you can use Jhipster to create a project and add an appropriate dependency 
take look at this resource :
[Jhipster](https://www.jhipster.tech/)